# How do I pass a model property to a partial view with a different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, renderpartial

Given a view model class

```
public class Foo 
{
   public string Fuzz { get; set; }
   public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
   public string Fizz { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller action I pass the following model to the view:

```
View(new Foo { Fuzz = "Fizz", Bar = new Bar{ Fizz = "Fuzz" } });
```

In the view Foo.cshtml

```
@model Foo

@Model.Fuzz

@{ Html.RenderPartial("BarPartial", Model.Bar); }
```

In the view partial BarPartial.cshtml

```
@model Bar

@Model.Fizz
```

An error is thrown:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type Foo but this dictionary requires a model item of type Bar.

How do I pass a property of the parent model to a partial view with a model that is a type of the property?

Comment: It should work exactly as you showed it here. Are you sure you did it exatly that way in your "real code"?

Comment: Hint: Instead of `@{ Html.RenderPartial("BarPartial", Model.Bar); }` you can use also the shorter `@Html.Partial("BarPartial", Model.Bar)`.

Comment: Thanks chrfin, it actually works on a new MVC5 project. But there must be something wrong with the other project where I am getting this error.

Comment: i try this, but your code work fine at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ActionResult test2()
        {
            return View(new Foo { Fuzz = "Fizz", Bar = new Bar { Fizz = "Fuzz" } });
        }
```

my view

```
@model Foo

@Model.Fuzz
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_partial1",Model.Bar); }
```

my partial

```
@model Bar

@Model.Fizz
```

no different code, and work great for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I just figured out the error:

It seems in the real project I was working on the model I was passing was being set to null in later parts of the action code.

This error will occur:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type Foo but this dictionary requires a model  item of type Bar.
```

if

```
View(new Foo { Fuzz = "Fizz", Bar = null });
```